# Accessing Member Variable Inside Overridden Base Class Function

Tags: c++, member-variables

How do I access member variables inside an overridden base class function?

```
//Overridden base class function
void handleNotification(s3eKey key){
     //Member variable of this class
     keyPressed = true; //Compiler thinks this is undeclared.
}
```

Complier is complaining that keyPressed is not declared. The only way I can figure out how to access it is declare keyPressed as a public static variable and then use something like:

```
ThisClass::keyPressed = true;
```

What am I doing wrong?

//Added details-----------------------------------------------------------

ThisClass.h:

```
include "BaseClass.h"

class ThisClass: public BaseClass {
private:
    bool keyPressed;
};
```

ThisClass.cpp:

```
include "ThisClass.h"

//Overridden BaseClass function
void handleNotification(s3eKey key){
     //Member variable of ThisClass
     keyPressed = true; //Compiler thinks this is undeclared.
}
```

BaseClass.h:

```
class BaseClass{
public:
    virtual void handleNotification(s3eKey key);
};
```

BaseClass.cpp

```
include 'BaseClass.h"

void BaseClass::handleNotification(s3eKey key) {
}
```

Comment: Is the function body inside or outside the class definition? A complete, minimal example would help.

Comment: I'll add some more details. C++ is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to override a function is as follows.

```
class base {
protected:
  int some_data;
  virtual void some_func(int);
public:
  void func(int x) { some_func(x); }
};

void base::some_func(int x)
{ /* definition, may be in some source file. */ }

class derived : public base
{
protected:
  virtual void some_func(int);  // this is not base::some_func() !
};

void derived::some_func(int x)
{
  some_data = x; // example implementation, may be in some source file
}
```

**edit** Note that `base::some_func()` and `derived::some_func()` are two different functions, with the latter overriding the former.

Comment: Thanks! So you have to re-declare something that was already declared in the base class?

Comment: @user3564870, that is correct. That's the only way to tell the compiler that the derived class has an implementation that overrides the implementation in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Is this method defined outside of the class definition? In other words, is your code structured like so:

```
class ThisClass {
    ...
};

// method defined outside of the scope of ThisClass declaration, potentially
// in a completely different file
void handleNotification(s3eKey key) {
    ....
}
```

If so, you need to declare the method like this:

```
void ThisClass::handleNotification(s3eKey key){
    keyPresssed = true;
}
```

Otherwise the compiler will not know that the `handleNotification()` method being implemented is the one which belongs to `ThisClass`. Rather, it will assume that it is *not* part of the `ThisClass` implementation, so it won't have automatic access to `ThisClass`'s variables.

Comment: If I try to do that, it complains: "Out-of-line definition of "handleNotification" does not match any declaration in 'ThisClass'.

Comment: this means that you have failed to declare the function.

Comment: It's declared in BaseClass.h.

Comment: You will need to declare it in `ThisClass.h` as well.